# How to align text content instead of the text view for Texts inside VStack

Tags: swiftui

As you can see from the screenshot below two `Text`s in the `VStack` are left aligned to the left edge of the text view but not actual content. How to align the **text content** inside the view instead of the view?

[image]
[image]

```
struct Content: View {
    var body: some View {
        return VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("LARGE")
                .lineLimit(1)
                .font(
                    .system(size: 120.0,
                            weight: .medium, design: .monospaced))

            Text("SMALL")
                .lineLimit(1)
                .font(.system(size: 50.0,
                              weight: .medium, design: .monospaced))
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(Content())
```

Comment: As you can see the VStack aligned properly ie; The red and yellow background leading is aligned perfectly. The issue appears due to the letter spacing, If you changed `.monospaced` to `.default` you will get it properly aligned. I don't know the reason :(